# Parse string with `T` to timestamp PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this string `2019-02-14T17:49:20.987` which I want to parse into a timestamp. So I am playing with the `to_timestamp` function and it seems to work fine except... The problem is with this T letter there. How do I make PostgreSQL skip it?
What pattern should I use in `to_timestamp`?

Of course I can replace the T with a space and then parse it but I find this approach too clumsy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)

> If there are characters in the template string that are not template patterns, the corresponding characters in the input data string are simply skipped over (whether or not they are equal to the template string characters).

So just put any non-template character there (e.g. `X`):

```
select to_timestamp('2019-02-14T17:49:20.987', 'YYYY-MM-DDXHH24:MI:SS.MS')
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/OHYD18205

Alternatively, you can simply cast the value:

```
select '2019-02-14T17:49:20.987'::timestamp
```

Comment: I tried this of course... But my pattern was in uppercase. And that didn't work, gave me an error. Hm... The case of the pattern - does it matter? In the official docs there patterns are given in uppercase. I wonder why the case matters here.

Comment: @peter.petrov: what is your Postgres version (`select version();` will tell you)

Comment: Wait... This pattern does not work `select to_timestamp('2019-02-14T17:49:20.987', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.MS');` So if the pattern is in upper case the parsing does not work, right?  My version is: PostgreSQL 10.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit

Comment: Anyway... Thanks. Should be something really subtle. To avoid complications I will just replace the T with a space. Thanks. But it's quite interesting to know why it behaves this way.

Comment: @peter.petrov: see my edit, you can also cast that value

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too (just casting) but I wanted my code to be explicit rather than implicit. Thanks again.

Comment: @peter.petrov I've had to do this as well, and our coding convention is to always use uppercase for these things, so the pattern is in uppercase... all you have to do is put T in quotes, i.e. `'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.MS'` and it will work correctly.

Comment: The trick is to use a character that is not a "template" character at all (the `T` is used in some patterns)

Comment: Ugh, I put a space character as my non-template filler, which didn't seem to help. The `X` worked.

Answer (score 3):

The string with `T` is a valid input literal for `timestamp` or `timestamptz`:

```
select '2019-02-14T17:49:20.987'::timestamp;

        timestamp        
-------------------------
 2019-02-14 17:49:20.987
(1 row)
```